# In JES which I believe is Python 2, how do I do a nested for loop to count reps until a list is sorted

Tags: python, jes

I am taking a beginners programming class using JES which I believe is Python 2.
My teacher has asked that we create an empty list and then add random numbers to it, then sort it from lowest to highest.  That part I have done correctly.  The extra credit is to add a nested for loop that will count the reps it takes to sort the list.
This is what I have:

```js
from random import *

def main():

# create list of 25 (this can be changed to number of your choice) random numbers from -100 to 100
# print list with message "list before shuffling"
  numList = []
  count = 0
  while count < 15:
    num = randint( -100 , 100 )
    numList.append(num)
    count = count + 1
  printNow("the List before shuffling:  " +str(numList))
  n = len(numList)
  add = 0
# Randomly shuffle list with items only moving if a lower number is being switched with a larger number
# do this 1000 times ( this can be changed to number of your choice)
# print list with message "list after shuffling"
  for reps in range (0 , 500):
    i = randrange(0, n)
    j = randrange(0, n)
# extra credit, add nested for loop to count number of reps it takes to sort the list    
    for sort in range(0, len(numList)):
      for item in range(sort+1, len(numList)):
        while numList[sort] < numList[item] or add < reps:
          add = add + 1
       
    if i < j:
      if numList[i] > numList[j]:
        temp = numList[i]
        numList[i] = numList[j]            
        numList[j] = temp
    elif j < i:
      if numList[i] < numList[j]:
        temp = numList[j]
        numList[j] = numList[i]
        numList[i] = temp
        
  print(" List was sorted in " + str(add) + " reps.")
  printNow("The List after shuffling:  " +str(numList))
```

My teacher says that I have too many loops in my extra credit section.  I am stuck and am looking for someone to explain what I am doing wrong.
I DO NOT want someone to solve it for me, but tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that is any reason for you to put a `while` loop within your two-level `for` loop. With two `for` loops, you should be able to iterate through your list and use some other conditional-checker (hint: that you have already used in this script you've shown) to determine whether the current list element is in the right spot (for the moment - may be shuffled around later). You could look in to:

> bubble sort

Comment: Ok, I changed the while statement to an if statement.  That seems to make the program run, but it is still not running correctly.  Is that what you meant or should I have taken out the conditional statement altogether?

Comment: In my new If statement, I have changed the or to an and and that seems to make it work.  I think I have it now. Thanks